# Crontab running a script in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Have a simple script to run top comman nand store the result in txt file.It will run a loop 3 times a day with 1 hour gap.Once done the email will be sent using the text file content as the body of email and delete the text file so next day new text file.

**Problem**

1. To automate the process i have create the cronjob to start at 8.30 pm,which will start the script and my script will keep runing for 4 hours and the result of the command will be appeneded in text file and finally sent over mail.CRON is >> `0 10 * * * /tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/Report.sh`

> /tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/Report.sh: line 34: ReportProd.txt: Permission denied
>   
>   **Code**

For generating txt file

```
{
//Some Logic
} >> ReportProd.txt   //Running script manually works great and generate txt!!
```

Delete the file after mailing.

```
find /tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/*.txt -type f -delete   //This works fine manually,file is getting generated and deleted also.
```

> /tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/Report.sh: line 39: ReportProd.txt: No such file or directory

Can you help me out what could be the problem here? i have goggled few things but not hitting the right point.
 Given all the permission to the folder 0755 in expectation that the cron would execute without any problem.
`Tried giving cd and path and then the command in crontab but seems not working`

- is it possible to give permission like only crontab would be able to
  access the code and the owner,no one else.

**NOTE** : Not added #!/bin/bash and "whereis sh" gives me sh: /bin/sh /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/sh.1p.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, make sure that you `cd` to the directory you want the output file `ReportProd.txt` to be created in.  The script will attempt to create it in the *current directory* which will have a different value when cron runs it.
Simply running the script with `/tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/Report.sh` doesn't mean the working directory will be `/tmp/ssh-abc/KKK`.

Alternately, supply the full path you want the output file to go to.  For example:

```
{
# Output generated here
} >> /full/path/to/output/ReportProd.txt
```

Comment: You saved my life :) Damn!! this would help many noobs in bash scripting like me.
Two places : while generating text file and attaching the file to email.

Answer (score 0):

Try 0 10 * * * sudo sh /tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/Report.sh

That's how i do it, and usually have no problems.
Cron job should be installed as root with crontab -e

Comment: may i know what do you mean installed as root?
When i type crontab -e when am in the home directory it shows me the cronjob i have scheduled.So does that mean the cron job is installed as root?

Comment: If you are root when running crontab -e, then yes, it is installed as root. But also check that your executable has executable attributes, as other answer mentioned

Comment: ::Getting this message in mail `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: maybe this can help with sudo http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password

Answer (score -1):

try doing

```
/bin/sh /tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/Report.sh
```

or do

```
chmod 755 /tmp/ssh-abc/KKK/Report.sh
```

may be the script is not executable.

Comment: Same way the script is working on other server where i do not have any tmp folder and directly usr folder inside that my username folder is there.If it is not executable it should not run there too? Please correct me if am going wrong.

Comment: why don't you just check ls -l Report.sh